# Get invalid Validators in formControlName

Tags: angular

For example I have Validators below

```
username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(...)], this.validateUsernameNotTaken.bind(this)]
```

If this username is invalid I want know if it`s caused by async validator or not. Also I want get any information about invalid not-async validators.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ValidatorFn` is a function that takes your `FormControl` and returns a `ValidationErrors` or `null` if the value is valid :

```
interface ValidatorFn {
  (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null
}
```

Similarly, a `AsyncValidatorFn` is a function that takes your `FormControl` and returns an `Observable<ValidationErrors | null>` (or a `Promise`)

```
interface AsyncValidatorFn {
  (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null>
}
```

In both cases, they produce some `ValidationErrors` that you can get in `FormControl.errors`